# Python, Celery, Flask, "working outside of application context"

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to schedule tasks using Celery and Python for a Flask app. I basically want to run a function in another directory every x amount of time and make it a celery task. I import the function test_check and I try and put it under a celery task called testcheck(), however, I get the error:

> working outside of application context

How can I fix this? Here is my setup:

```
from app import app
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from app.mod_check.views import test_check

celery = Celery(__name__,
             broker='amqp://guest:@localhost/',
             backend='amqp://guest:@localhost/'
             )

celery.config_from_object(__name__)

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    print "celery working!"
    return x + y

@celery.task
def testcheck():
        test_check()

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks2.testcheck',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        #'args': (16, 16)
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/London'
```

Comment: Have you seen the [official Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/) on this?

Comment: @jonafato with that approach I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'`

Answer (score 3):

Whatever `test_check` is, it does something that needs a request context.  Since Celery tasks are not part of the HTTP request/response cycle, you need to set up a request context manually.

```
with app.test_request_context():
    test_check()
```